# Gensim Extracting TF-IDF value of a word in a corpus

Tags: python, text, tf-idf, gensim

I'm using Gensim TfidfModel model. this is my code:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split()) for line in open('aaa.txt'))

class MyCorpus(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for line in open('aaa.txt'):
            yield dictionary.doc2bow(line.lower().split())

corpus = MyCorpus()

tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)

corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]
```

now I want to extract tf-idf value of each word, I know that they are in corpus_tfidf variable and I tried some codes like below to view all of words tf-idf but I have a word like 'banana' and I want to find its tf-idf value. there is a access to find each word in dictionary like dictionary.token2id['banana'] but how can I get tf-idf of each word?

```
{dictionary.get(id): value for doc in corpus_tfidf for id, value in doc}
```

My corpus has 6501598 documents, 585499 features, 64106768 non-zero entries, and it's important to get value of each word in minimum time.